# question on tomcat for serving of webapps and web-inf

Tags: java, javascript, web-applications, tomcat

There is a project deployed in Tomcat.
The web-app of course in is `webapps` of tomcat and the structure is as follows:

```
tomcat-home
|--webapps
       |
        -MyProject
                 |
                  -WEB-INF
                  -startingPoint.js
                  -client
                  -other dirs etc
```

Now startingPoint.js is a javascript file that essentially loads an applet in the browser and is similar to this:

```
document.write('<OBJECT ');
document.write('  codebase = "jre.exe" WIDTH = "100%" HEIGHT = "100%" MAYSCRIPT > ');
document.write('  <PARAM NAME = CODE VALUE = "com/AnApplet.class" > ');
document.write('  <PARAM NAME = CODEBASE VALUE = "/MyProject/client/classes" >');
document.write('  <PARAM NAME = ARCHIVE VALUE = "/MyProject/client/lib/Appletclient.jar"> ');
document.write('  <PARAM NAME = "type" VALUE = "application/x-java-applet;version=1.6"> ');
document.write('  <PARAM NAME = "MAYSCRIPT" VALUE="true"> ');
etc.
```

If I write in the IE url bar the url:
http://ip:port/MyProject  (tomcat is running of course) the applet is loaded in my browser but I can not understand how.
I mean from web.xml I can not see something that would serve the javascript file.
If a js file is in the roor directory of my project, does it get automatically served?
I feel I am missing something here.
Could someone please advice, what is it here I should be looking for?

Thanks

Comment: Is there a welcome file in `WEB-INF/web.xml` ?

Comment: There is the mention of index.html and index.htm in welcomefile, yes

Comment: Is there and index.htm or index.html in the root of MyProject?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either this `.js` is included in your `welcome-page` specified in `web.xml` or in `index` page ,

That page will get loaded and with that if js is included it will load.

Comment: @Org.life.java:You mean without explicitely writing the index page in the url bar?There is the welcome file list with the index.html and index.htm as well, but I do not see an index.html in the root dir of the project

Comment: there might be servlet mapping associated with some other file. try searching which page gets loaded when you type `http://ip:port/MyProject` by seeing at HTML [ if you aren't comfortable with servlet mapping] and check that js file should be loaded from there

Comment: I understand what you are saying.But there is no servlet mapping with url pattern of /MyProject

Comment: try searching for it in your application. it must be there

Answer (score 1):

The `index.jsp` (or any file configured in the `<welcome-file-list>` located in the root of the web application is served by default.

If you don't have such a file, it depends on another settings whether to show a listing of the directory, or deny access.

Comment: There is a welcome file list, mentioning index.html and index.htm (I think that if one uses an ide to auto create a web.xml these are created by default) but no mention of javascript file.I do not know what I should be looking for here

Comment: No, I do not see it in the root directory

Answer (score 0):

Hi
Another approach could be,
You just write a  index.jsp/ index.html. 
Include your js in the file.

Call .js on

```
<body onload=foo();>
```